# Where can I find good, reliable Drupal freelancers?

Tags: 7

I've looked on Elance, Guru, etc for skilled, reliable Drupal freelancers without any luck.  Are there any suggestions for where to look for these folks?  Remote workers are fine for what I need done.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your complaint about E-lance? I have a profile on my own up there, but I'm to busy with my full-time Drupal job to be active on there.

Comment: It would be great if this site would add a feature for drop jobs/projects. But this should probably discussed in meta ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of generic freelancer site members may have used Drupal but usually work with anything, wordpress, joomla etc. Drupal has a fairly high learning curve and to get the best out of it you would be best with a Drupal Expert. Maybe try something closer to the Drupal community.

Using a Drupal resource for Drupal freelancers might provide more Drupal expertise...

http://drupal.org/paid-services 
http://drupal.org/marketplace-preview

Answer (score 1):

You can try #drupal-consultants on IRC, freenode.

Mailing list: http://lists.drupal.org/listinfo/consulting

Forum: http://drupal.org/paid-services

Drupal groups:

1. http://groups.drupal.org/consulting
2. http://groups.drupal.org/available-for-hire